# Twitter Authorization with version 1.1 of the API

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have had a search around stackoverflow, but was unable to find an answer to my question, so I thought I'd ask.

I'm currently working on an iOS app where I would like to get a feed of a public timeline without the user of the app being required to have a twitter account.

I am successfully able to do this using twitters v1.0 of the API and all works perfectly. Simply making a request to http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=username retrieves all the information that I require.

However, since v1.0 has been deprecated and V1.1 requires authentication for each request, I get a bad authorization error using this API. Having looked at the Twitter documentation and how to generate OAuth request headers, I don't fully understand the "Getting a signing key" section of the documentation in the link below. (this is my first time working with Twitter's API and OAuth, I'm trying to gain a good understanding, before I start the implementation)

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

As I understand it, the consumer secret can be found when logging into twitter.com/apps but I'm not sure where I would get the "OAuth Token Secret" in order to generate a valid signing key.

Since this is an iOS app, I know I could use the TWRequest class, but to my understanding, this would require the user to have twitter setup on their device.

I hope the above makes sense and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Anonymous access won't work with v1.1. Would it be so bad for you to require the users to have twitter set up on their devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Twitter application you have set up https://dev.twitter.com/apps

You should see your Access token secret under the heading **Your access token**.  If you don't see this then you probably haven't generated an access token yet.

Comment: I figured it out in the end, and this is exactly what I had to do, Thanks